# Put float after (empty) paragraph

Tags: floats, positioning, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

My code looks roughly as follows:

```
\clearpage
\subsubsection{mySubSubSection}
\paragraph{because SubSubSubSections don't exist}
\begin{figure}[H]\includegraphics[]{fig1}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]\includegraphics[]{fig2}\end{figure}
```

But it gets printed as:

---

### mySubSubSection

[figure 1]

[figure 2]

**because SubSubSubSections don't exist**

---

and I want it to be printed as

---

### mySubSubSection

**because SubSubSubSections don't exist**

[figure 1]

[figure 2]

---

I've tried everything in my power. `\clearpage`, the `float` package with `[H]` figure option, naked `\includegraphics` (doesn't work because then I can't use captions), ...

Any suggestions? This shouldn't be so hard.
I'm using LuaLaTex

Comment: You need to add `figure` placement options. For example `\begin{figure}[ht]`

Comment: I have those. Sorry if that wasn't clear - I'll update the question.

Comment: note if you just used `\includegraphics` it would stay where you put it, the only purpose of the `figure` environment is to specify its content may be moved to help with page breaking.

Comment: There is no need to use the figure environment. includegraphics works well without.

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein and DavidCarlisle I appreciate your attempt at help but I literally specified that using a naked \includegraphics doesn't work because then I can't use captions.

Comment: @PDiracDelta you did but (a) it's not correct, you can use `\captionof` and (b) you added that text in an edit that overlapped us writing the comments even though they posted a minute earlier.

Comment: @PDiracDelta Ok, but that can be fixed with \captionof{figure}{Figure's Caption} instead of \caption, which only works in figure environment. Check, which additional package to load. \usepackage{capt-of}
or
\usepackage{caption}
or
\documentclass{scrartcl}
or
\documentclass{scrbook}
or
\documentclass{scrreprt}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please always provide a test file.

As you are using `[H]` the float will not float, but `\paragraph` is an *inline* heading so it is deferred until the start of a paragraph, so you need to give it an empty`\mbox{}` to attach to.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{mySubSubSection}
\paragraph{because SubSubSubSections don't exist}
\mbox{}
\begin{figure}[H]\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: alternatively redeclare `\paragraph` to be a display heading.

Comment: This works, thanks a million! I now understand why it didn't at first.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `\includegraphics` with a caption provided by the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package.

```
% figplaceprob.tex  SE 588524
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \includegraphics and provides the example images
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\clearpage
\subsubsection{mySubSubSection}
\paragraph{because SubSubSubSections don't exist}
%\begin{figure}[H]\includegraphics[]{fig1}\end{figure}
%\begin{figure}[H]\includegraphics[]{fig2}\end{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{First}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Second}
\end{center}
Followed, perhaps by some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]